# Filtered Numpy Array Changes Number of Dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

I'm having trouble getting used to Numpy arrays (I'm a Matlab user). When I try to select just a range of values from an array, I see the resulting array has an extra dimension:

```
    ioi = np.nonzero((self.data_array[0,:] >= range_start) & (self.data_array[0,:] <= range_end))

    print("self.data_array.shape = {0}".format(self.data_array.shape))
    print("self.data_array.shape[:,ioi] = {0}".format(self.data_array[:,ioi].shape))
```

The result is:

```
self.data_array.shape = (5, 50000)
self.data_array.shape[:,ioi] = (5, 1, 408)
```

I also see that ioi is a tuple. I don't know if that has anything to do with it.

What is happening here to create that extra dimension and what should I do, in the most direct way, to get an array shape of (5,408) in this case?

Comment: `data_array[:, ioi[0]]` should give you the desired shape.  This pulls the index array out of the tuple.  Otherwise `[:, ioi]` is equivalent to `[:, np.array(ioi)]` which adds the initial size 1 dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest and most efficient thing would be to get rid of the `np.nonzero` call, and use logical indexing just as one would in Matlab. Here's an example. (I'm using random data of the same shape, FYI.)

```
>>> data = np.random.randn(5, 5000)
>>> start, end = -0.5, 0.5
>>> ioi = (data[0] > start) & (data[0] < end)
>>> print(ioi.shape)
(5000,)
>>> print(ioi.sum())
1900
>>> print(data[:, ioi].shape)
(5, 1900)
```

The `np.nonzero` call is not usually needed. Just like Matlab's `find` function, it's slow compared with logical indexing, and usually one's goal can be more efficiently accomplished with logical indexing. `np.nonzero`, just like `find`, should mostly be used only when you need the actual index values themselves.

As you suspected, the reason for the extra dimensions is that tuples are handled differently from other types of indexing arrays in NumPy. This is to allow more flexible indexing, such as with `slice`s, ellipses, etc. See [this useful page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html) for in-depth explanation, especially the last section.

There are at least two other options to solve the problem. One is to use the `ioi` array, as returned from `np.nonzero`, directly as your *only* index to the data array. As in: `self.data_array[ioi]`. Part of why you have an extra dimension is that you actually have *two* set of indices in your call: the slice (`:`) and the tuple `ioi`. `np.nonzero` is guaranteed to return a tuple exactly for this reason, so that its output can always be used to directly index the source array.

The last option is to call `np.squeeze` on the returned array, but I'd opt for one of the above first.